# Unable to install REBOUND in Python with pip

Tags: python, gcc, pip, installation

I want to install the [REBOUND](https://rebound.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library for Python 2.7 and Python 3.7 in my fresh Fedora 29.

I tried:

```
python -m pip install --user rebound
```

This finds the package indeed (I also tried several combinations of parameters using dnf and yum but those were unable to find the package) but the wheel fails and gcc also. I don't know how to do this. I've installed several packages without any problem (`numpy`, `matplotlib`, `scipy`, `keras`, etc.) but for REBOUND things go wrong somehow.

Here is the error I'm getting:

> ```
>    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7
>    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
>    ----------------------------------------
> Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-
> install-zOfeCV/rebound/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', 
> open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
> __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-KVSdkl/install-record.txt 
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error 
> code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-zOfeCV/rebound/
> ```

I've placed the full log in a pastebin as the log was lengthy. ([Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/LKuXxf1s))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `libpython2.7`? Try `locate -b libpython2.7`. On my Debian there are `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.a` and `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so`. If they aren't there install the libraries with

```
sudo yum install python-devel
```

Comment: It worked! I located both but after a `sudo dnf install python-devel` I could finally install rebound. Thank you sir.